# How to write a loop in R to perform a statistical test multiple times on two sets of randomly generated values

Tags: r, loops, random

Using R,
I have two vectors a and b:

```
a <- rnorm(3, mean = 6, sd = 2)
b <- rnorm(3, mean = 8, sd = 2)
```

I want to generate `a` and `b` a specified number of times and each time perform a `t.test` comparing the mean of `a` and the mean of `b`

```
t.test(a, b, paired = FALSE)
```

How do I code repeating the `rnorm` and `t.test` functions a specified number of times and retrieving the full output of the `t.test()` or just the `p.value`

Comment: Create a function for a single test. Use `replicate()` to repeat it as many times as you want.

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of the function?

Comment: Ok, I think this is what you mean ```replicate(20, t.test(rnorm(3, mean = 6, sd = 2), rnorm(3, mean = 8, sd = 2))$p.value)```

Comment: Yes. That is the easiest way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on your comment:

```
pvals <- replicate(20, t.test(rnorm(3, mean = 6, sd = 2), rnorm(3, mean = 8, sd = 2))$p.value)
sum(pvals < .05)
# [1] 2
hist(pvals)
```

To get all of the results

```
results <- replicate(20, t.test(rnorm(3, mean = 6, sd = 2), rnorm(3, mean = 8, sd = 2)), simplify=FALSE)
results[[1]]
# 
#   Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  rnorm(3, mean = 6, sd = 2) and rnorm(3, mean = 8, sd = 2)
# t = 0.052882, df = 2.6225, p-value = 0.9616
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -8.880021  9.155836
# sample estimates:
# mean of x mean of y 
#  7.156974  7.019067
```

With the other results being results[[2]], . . . , results[[20]]. The `simplify=FALSE` argument is needed to preserve the list structure of each run.